# AngularJS Dependency Injection Principle

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

What is the magic behind auto resolving dependencies in AngularJS?

```
angular
    .module('app', [])
    .service('appService', 
        function appService (firstService, secondService, thirdService) { }
```

How are *firstService, secondService, thirdService* automatically injected?

Comment: Take a look at http://www.alexrothenberg.com/2013/02/11/the-magic-behind-angularjs-dependency-injection.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript Automatic **Dependency Injection** is based on [*Function.prototype.toString()*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/toString) method that returns a string representation of the object in the form of a function declaration.

The returned string is parsed with regular expression to find function arguments and return its names that will be used to find, instantiate and inject real services.

```
(function appService (firstService,secondService,thirdService) {})
    .toString()
    .match(/^function\s*[^\(]*\(\s*([^\)]*)\)/m)[1]
    .split(',')

// => ["firstService", "secondService", "thirdService"]
```